# Bind Exclude Asp.net WebForms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, .net-4.5, model-binding

Hi in reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149390/modelstate-based-on-navigation-property-is-evaluating-to-false) i want to ask if there is something like `[Bind(Exclude="prop")]` in Asp.Net WebForms ? which is introduced with .net 4.5

Comment: I fail to see the difference between this question, and the other one you asked.  Is there, in fact,  a difference?

Comment: well there is none but in the other question i asked about a specific technique which is not working and in this one i have asked if any thing that is available that would work ....